How can I make the top navigation links open up in a new tab for SharePoint 2019?
How can I make the top navigation links open up in a new tab for SharePoint 2019?
I don't see the option to do it like SharePoint Online has?

Do you mean the link which was set in "Top Link Bar" in Site settings? You have to right click it and select Open in new tab.

